# How to combine two object lists into one list by id in rxjs using observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have two service calls that return with an observable list:

> service.getAllUsers(): observable<User[]> where User looks like this:

```
    User {
     id: number,
     username: string,
     ...
    }
```

and the other service call:

> service.getSomeData() : Observable<Data[]>

```
 Data {
  userId: number,
  userSomeData1,
  userSomeData2,
  ...
}
```

I want to merge these two lists into one Observable list, based on userId:

> Observable<Result[]>

where Result should looks like this:

```
 Result {
  id,
  username,
  userSomeData1,
  userSomeData2,
  ...
}
```

What I have done so far:

```
const result$ = this.userService.getAllUsers()
                .pipe(switchMap(users => {
                   return this.userService.getSomeData()
                    .pipe(map(data => ({users, data})))
                }))
```

But its not what I want.
Please help me, how can I achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was very close, you just need to `.map()` each element in your users array to a new object with the corresponding data item appended:

```js
const result$ = this.userService.getAllUsers().pipe(
    switchMap(users => this.userService.getSomeData().pipe(
        map(data => users.map(
            u => ({...u, ...data.find(d => d.userId === u.id)})
        ))
    })
));
```

Comment: In your example I would get a `users.map is not a function`?

Comment: Your `userService.getAllUsers()` must not be returning an array.

Comment: Why may no array be returned. My userService.getAllUsers() return a Observable<User[]>.

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯          maybe post a new question with your relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, make the two api calls, run a `map` on the array, find the data for the respective user and finally merge using array destructuring!

```
    const result$ = forkJoin([
        this.userService.getAllUsers(),
        this.userService.getSomeData(),
    ]).pipe(
        map(([users, data]) => {
            return users.map(user => {
                let clonedData = user;
                const foundData = data.find(x => x.userId === user.id);
                if (foundData) {
                    clonedData = { ...clonedData, ...foundData };
                }
                return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(clonedData));
            });
        })
    );
```